# Logstash relative filepath error when referencing Windows file

Tags: logstash

I am trying to read a local .jsonlines file on my Windows machine and keep getting the following error:

File paths must be absolute, relative path specified: path => "C:\Users[rest of my filepath].jsonlines"

Here is my config file:

```
input { 
   file { 
        path => "C:\Users\[rest of my filepath].jsonlines"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
 }
}


filter {
json{
  source => "message" }
 } 


output {
  csv {
    fields => ["myfield1","myfield2","myfield3"]
    path => "C:\Users\ [rest of my filepath].csv"
}
}
```

Here's what I have already tried:

1. Changing my filepath to linux-style (e.g. C:/Users/[rest of my filepath].jsonlines)
2. Lower-casing the C (e.g. "c:\ Users[rest of my filepath].jsonlines")
3. Using a double \ \ (e.g. "C: \ \Users[rest of my filepath].jsonlines"
4. Used double \ \ for all directories (e.g. "C: \ \Users \ \ restof \  \ [filepath].jsonlines")

What is the deal? I see that there are issues around Windows filepaths but the suggestions I've found (see above) haven't worked.
I am using Windows 10 and Windows 7, Logstash version 1.5.6 (unable to update to 2.x at this time).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a later version of Logstash (1.5.5 worked, and 2.3.1 worked). Ended up installing 2.3.1 and all is well.